# Autolayout and embeded scroll views

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view that contains a scroll view and that scroll view has another 2 views in it: on top a standard view, and under that another view. This last view has a scroll view inside it. (a matroshka doll has nothing on this app) .
The problem is there is a button that causes the bottom view to resize and increase it's height, but the outer scroll view doesn't increase content size. So the bottom part of the bottom view (now resized to be bigger) is not visible.

Any suggestions on how to fix this mess ?

Comment: can you please edit your code her.. else paste your expected output as rough diagram..